# how to convert delimited string of integers into hex in python

Tags: python, hex, string-formatting

How to convert a delimited string of integers to equivalent in python

For example i have a string that contains integers delimited by colon (:)

```
int_string = "1558662:10306104:11038113:7883355"
```

How to convert the above int_string into equivalent hex_string shown below

```
hex_string = "17C886:9D4238:A86DA1:784A5B"
```

How can this be done in a clean syntax?

Comment: What have you tried, and what are your ideas? Something doesn't work? Split the string, convert to integers, and join back together rendering as hex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
>>> int_string = '1558662:10306104:11038113:7883355'
>>> hex_string = ':'.join(format(int(i), 'X') for i in int_string.split(':'))
>>> hex_string
'17C886:9D4238:A86DA1:784A5B'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hex_string = ':'.join(map("{:X}".format, map(int, int_string.split(':'))))
```

*Gives:*

```
17C886:9D4238:A86DA1:784A5B
```